# VNC Server .Net Library

Tags: .net, network-protocols, vnc-server

I'm looking for a .NET component which aid me the introduction of VNC communication compatibility to an application.

The application already installs necessary Windows hook, so I'm interested only on a library which able me to communicate with VNC clients without re-implementing the VNC protocol.

Is there such library?

If it is possible, I'd like to have a closed license compatible components (i.e. LGPL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VNCSharp](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/) is a client library. I'm unsure of its full abilities, as VNC allows both "client" and "server" to act as each other; but it should be a good starting point. That said, as far as I know, it may be the only .NET starting point as its the only .NET VNC component I've ever been able to locate.